# How to show all annot numbers in the heatmap on seaborn?

Tags: matplotlib, scikit-learn, seaborn, visualization

[Here is the photo attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4hwg.png)

I tried to update seaborn with conda update seaborn on anaconda command prompt, it was up to update. I also tried to update scipy/sci-kit learn, nothing is changing. It is remaining missing labels.

Comment: This is a known matplotlib bug.